# Run RavenDB as a service with custom VirtualDirectory appSettings

Tags: ravendb

I need to run RavenDB as a service, but with custom VirtualDirectory set.
I put such setting into `Raven.Server.exe.config` file:

```
<add key="Raven/Port" value="80"/>
<add key="Raven/VirtualDirectory" value="/RavenDB"/>
```

But then when I run `Raven.Server.exe /restart` and try to access raven:

```
http://localhost/RavenDB
```

It gives me 404 error status response - `Route invalid`

Any ides why it doesn't except my settings?

Comment: I think that you shouldn't use the prefix /

Comment: @AyendeRahien the same, it doesn't work, I tried both variants - with and without prefix. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try running this as a service, see what is going on. It is possible that you don't have permissions to run with this path as a service.